# How to render the first element of a list different than others in DTL

Tags: django

I want to render the first element of a list differently in Django Template Language. How can I differentiate the first iteration from others? Or is there any different way?

I have tried doing -

```
{% for item in results %}
    {% if loop.first %}
        First Element
    {% else %}
        Other element
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you're using Jinja rather than Django template language?

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure. I'm using whatever comes in with django. I read somewhere it's jinja, maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: Yes, unless you have configured it specifically, it's not Jinja. It would be helpful if you could point to where you read it; I've been seeing this confusion a lot here lately and I would like to track down the source.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out! It's not jinja, I just looked at the doc!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [`forloop`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#for) instead of `loop`

```
{% for item in results %}
    {% if forloop.first %}
        First Element
    {% else %}
        Other element
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```